# socket.io - broadcast for a room

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Why broadcast for rooms doesn't work?
I feel I follow the documentation yet.
How to check that clients are present in the room?

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

socket.secure = true;

socket.on('connection', function (id_user) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('connection', id_user);

    var condition = { id_user: id_user };
    var query = dbh.query('SELECT `id_channel` FROM `TABG_pm_channel` WHERE ?', condition, function(err, rows, fields) {
        rows.forEach(function(row) {
            socket.join(row.id_channel);
            console.log('ajout de l\'user #'+id_user+' au salon #'+row.id_channel);
        });
    });

    console.log('Connection of user id '+id_user);
});

socket.on('disco', function (id_user) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('disco', id_user);
    console.log('Disconnection of user id '+id_user);
});

socket.on('privmsg', function (msg) {
    msg.text = sanitizer.sanitize(msg.text);

    post  = {id: '', id_channel: msg.id_channel, msg: msg.text, invitation: 0, id_sender: msg.id_sender, date: date()};
    dbh.query('INSERT INTO TABG_pm SET ?', post);

    socket.broadcast.to(post.id_channel).emit('new_privmsg', msg.text);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`io.sockets.clients('room')` will give you instances of all clients in the room.

https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Rooms